# Applications to use Java with

Tags: java, controls

I recently downloaded Java JDK, and installed it on my PC, yet I only received Java Mission Control, which is useless to me. Is there another way of getting programs to create apps in Java with?

Thanks :)

Comment: Java provides a programming language and a runtime environment. Get a text editor or, better yet, an IDE and start writing programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I have used 3 different IDEs them being:

1. IntelliJ
2. Netbeans
3. Eclipse

I personally, as being the first IDE that I used was Eclipse, but Netbeans is taking a great liking on me because of its ability to use multiple different languages in an easy to use interface. Although Eclipse being the greatest in my opinion because of its easy keybindings and a ton of useful plugins. IntelliJ is the least favourite of the 3 because I find it cumbersome, but that is just my opinion.

Comment: Thank you: the most detailed and helpful answer

Answer (score 1):

I would do a quick google search for "Eclipse IDE", it makes the process of developing a program much easier in my opinion. It may seem intimidating at first but just look up a few tutorials and you should be okay.

Comment: thanks for the effort

Answer (score 1):

find for 
`

1. eclips
2. netbeans

IDE but these IDE are for professionals who are hands on java

after some set of practice's use one of above IDE

if you want to remember and learn the concept of `.class` files, `packages`  and `command line` then go with

1. Notepad
2. Notepad++
3. Editplus

Comment: Thanks for the effort